# Android: ImageView is under the layout

Tags: android, android-xml

I have an imageview which has an animation. However, when the image moves, it goes behind its layout, as you can see in this image:
[image: my image]

I want that this imageview is in front of the layout. I tried with `yourView.bringToFront();` but in this way the imageview is in front of the other views, not the layout.

Here is the xml:

```
         <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/layoutComponentiNemico"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:orientation="vertical">

            <RelativeLayout
                android:id="@+id/layoutContenitoreImmagineNemico"
                android:layout_width="50dp"
                android:layout_height="0dp"
                android:layout_gravity="center"
                android:layout_weight="5">

                <ImageView
                    android:id="@+id/immagineNemico"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                    android:background="@drawable/anziano"/>
            </RelativeLayout>

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/immaginePiattaformaNemico"
                android:layout_width="150dp"
                android:layout_height="0dp"
                android:layout_gravity="center"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:background="@drawable/piattaformaritagliata"/>

        </LinearLayout>
```

So my imageview should "goes out" from the relative layout during the animation.

The animation:

```
    immagineNemico.clearAnimation();
    TranslateAnimation mAnimation = new TranslateAnimation(
            TranslateAnimation.RELATIVE_TO_PARENT, 0f,
            TranslateAnimation.RELATIVE_TO_PARENT, -0.4f,
            TranslateAnimation.RELATIVE_TO_PARENT, 0f,
            TranslateAnimation.RELATIVE_TO_PARENT, 0.1f);
    mAnimation.setDuration(1000);
    mAnimation.setRepeatCount(1);
    mAnimation.setRepeatMode(Animation.REVERSE);
    mAnimation.setInterpolator(new DecelerateInterpolator());
    immagineNemico.setAnimation(mAnimation);
```

Answer (score 0):

Could it be that you are applying the animation to `@id/layoutContenitoreImmagineNemico` instead of `@id/immaginePiattaformaNemico`?

Please show us your animation code.

Comment: @Curio you can't apply the animation directly to the imageview to achieve what you want. The ImageView is inside the layout, so when it goes out of the layout's bounds, the image disappears. Try to apply the animation to the layout itself and see if that works.

Comment: So do I have to apply the animation to both the imageview and the layout?

Comment: @Curio Just to the layout. Everything inside the layout will also move.

Comment: Only to layoutContenitoreImmagineNemico? I tried but it didn't work

Comment: Yes, I think only to layoutContenitoreImmagineNemico would work. What happened when you tried?

Comment: The image doesn't move. I am in a LinearLayout, maybe is this the motivation?

Comment: @curio Doesn't make sense. The translationX doesn't care about the layout. Try using animate().translationx() method in the layoutContenitoreImmagineNemico object instead.